# How can I make a html popup from flask?

Tags: python, html, flask, sqlite

I am creating a web application and am using flask on python along with it, I have created a registration system where the user can sign to the website and their details (email, username and password) which are saved in a sqlite3 database. I have made it so if the user enters a username or email, when registering, and that username or email is in the database it takes you back to the sign in page and does not save their data, **How can I make it so when it redirects you back to the form page a popup occurs with an error message?**

Html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class='signIn'>
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}

<body>

<center>
<form name='myForm' method="post" action="{{ url_for('signup') }}" style='text-align: center;'>
  <p>Email</p>
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder='Enter you email adress' required oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please enter a valid email ')" onchange="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}"></input>
  <p>Username</p>
  <input type="text" name="user" placeholder='Enter your username' required></input>
  <p>Password</p>
  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder='Enter your password' required></input>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Signup"></input>
   <a href="{{ url_for('home') }}" class='button_link'>Cancel</a>
</form>
</center>

</body>
{% endblock %}
</html>
```

Relevant python code:

```
def signup():
    cur = g.db.cursor()
    email = request.form['email']
    username = request.form['user']
    password = request.form['password']
    cur.execute("""SELECT email,username FROM users WHERE email=? OR username=?""",(email, username))
    result = cur.fetchone()
    if result:

        return redirect('/form/')

    else:
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES (?, ?, ?)", [email, username, password])
        g.db.commit()
        return redirect('/')
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not a pop-up, but you can use the flask's system for messaging. It's the `flash` command.

To use this in your code, it might look like this:

```py
if result:
    flash('You are already registered, please log in')

    return redirect('/form/')

else:
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO users VALUES (?, ?, ?)", [email, username, password])
    g.db.commit()
    flash('Thank you for registering')
    return redirect('/')
```